# What does "counted with multiplicity" mean in this proposition regarding roots of polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

*I may have come to understand it as I was writing this; reasoning in the last paragraph*

---

The proposition is as follows:

> Given any nonconstant polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, the number of roots of $f$, counted with multiplicity, is at most $\deg(f)$

I'm just getting hung up on the phrase "counted with multiplicity." I believe I understand the rest of the proposition. Using an example of a quadratic polynomial it's obvious to me that, vis a vis the quadratic formula, at most we could find $2$ roots.

What I understand about multiplicity is that, analogous to the prime factorization theorem for the integers, there is a theorem for polynomials that says that any nonconstant polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ can be factored as $$f = ap_{1} \cdots p_{k}$$ Where $a \in \mathbb{F}\ \text{and}\ p_1,...,p_k \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ are monic, irreducible polynomials. The multiplicity of $\alpha$ (a root of $f$) is then the number of times $(x - \alpha)$ shows up in the factorization. In other words it's the number of monic, irreducible polynomials $p_i$ that take the form above. Correct?

---

With that said, "counted with multiplicity", does that phrase simply suggest that the way we determined that at most  the number of roots can be $n$ for $\deg(f) = n$ is because $(x-\alpha)$ is a linear polynomial and linear polynomials are the lowest degree polynomial that can be irreducible so given the fact that $\deg(p_{1} \cdots p_{k}) = \deg(p_1) + \cdots \deg(p_k)$ the most we could potentially get is $n$ linear polynomials and thus $n$ polynomials of the form $(x-\alpha)$ and hence $n$ roots? Is that correct thinking?

Comment: I always read "counted with multiplicity" as "including copies."

Comment: Know that in the future, if you don't understand a phrase (like "counted with multiplicity"), you can put it into a search engine...

Comment: It is more than an "analogy" since if $D$ is a domain then $\,x-a\,$ is prime in $D[x]\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few different ways of looking at it:

---

**Admitting Copies:**

You can think of it as meaning "a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, when we allow for copies". For instance, in $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\R[x]$,
$$f(x) = x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x-1)^2$$
We count that $1$ twice, since its linear factor is squared. We could also write
$$f(x) = (x-1)(x-1)$$
for instance. And we know it is a root "twice" since $1$ is still a root of $f(x)/(x-1)$, which leads into another framing...

---

**Multisets:**

Consider defining a multiset. (A set will exclude repeat entries, i.e. $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, but a multiset does not.) Define, given $f \in \F[x]$,
$$
S_f := \left\{ (r,m) \in \F \times \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1} \,\middle|\, \frac{f(r)}{(x-r)^{m-1} } = 0 \right\}
$$
Then this theorem says that $|S_f| \le \deg(f)$. ($r$ corresponds to roots, and $m$ to multiplicity.)

To see how this works, consider the example

$$f(x) = (x-2)^3 (x-1)^2 (x+1) \in \R[x]$$

Then

- $f(x) = 0$ when $x=2$
- $f(x)/(x-2) = 0$ when $x=2$
- $f(x)/(x-2)^2 = 0$ when $x=2$
- $f(x) = 0$ when $x=1$
- $f(x)/(x-1) = 0$ when $x=1$
- $f(x) = 0$ when $x=-1$

but

- $f(x)/(x-2)^3 \ne 0$ for $x = 2$
- $f(x)/(x-1)^2 \ne 0$ for $x = 1$
- $f(x)/(x+1) \ne 0$ for $x = -1$

so

$$S_f = \{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(1,1),(1,2),(-1,1)\}$$

and $\deg(f) = 6 = |S_f|$.

---

**Factorization:**

Perhaps the most explicit: how would we write this out? Given the factorization of $f \in \F[x]$, we can write (for some $a \in \F$ and $r_i \in \F$ the roots with multiplicities $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$),
$$
f(x) = a \prod_i (x - r_i)^{m_i}
$$
Then the theorem says that $\displaystyle \deg(f) \ge \sum_i m_i$

---

**Addendum: "At Most"**

Not every $f \in \F[x]$ need factor into linear factors for given $f,\F$. Sometimes they do (in what we call an [algebraically closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field); $\mathbb{C}$ is an example of one). In the above examples, for simplicity, they did, but it might not hold in $\R[x]$ in general. For instance, $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ has zero roots in $\R$, hence the "at most".

Possibly already known to you but I wanted to address the possible contrived-ness of the examples.

---

> The multiplicity of $\alpha$ (a root of $f$) is then the number of times $(x - \alpha)$ shows up in the factorization. In other words it's the number of monic, irreducible polynomials $p_i$ that take the form above. Correct?

Yes, if you only allow powers of $1$ and write

$$f(x) = a \prod_{i=1}^{\deg(f)} (x - r_i) = a \prod_{i=1}^{\deg(f)} p_i(x)$$

(for $r_i$ roots and $p_i(x) := x-r_i$), then the number of times $p_i$ appears in that product is the multiplicity of the root $r_i$. (Though I feel somewhat adverse to this framing since then you have a bunch of root-multiplicity pairs that themselves are not distinct, but I suppose as long as it's not taken as a rigorous definition, all is fine.)

---

> does that phrase simply suggest that the way we determined that at most  the number of roots can be $n$ for $deg(f) = n$ is because $(x-\alpha)$ is a linear polynomial and linear polynomials are the lowest degree polynomial that can be irreducible so given the fact that $deg(p_{1} \cdots p_{k}) = deg(p_1) + \cdots deg(p_k)$ the most we could potentially get is $n$ linear polynomials and thus $n$ polynomials of the form $(x-\alpha)$ and hence $n$ roots?

Depends on how you look at it.

Are you suggesting this might be the proof? If so, I wouldn't be convinced.

As a heuristic? Yeah, sure, I suppose.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 3):

When you factor a polynomial over a field each root corresponds to a linear factor. Some linear factors may repeat. So for example if
$$
p(x) = (x - \alpha)^2(x-\beta)q(x)
$$
and $q$ has no roots in the field then $p$ has three roots: $\alpha$ with multiplicity two and $\beta$ (with multiplicity one).

Counting the number of linear factors counts the roots *with multiplicity*. Clearly the number of linear factors can't exceed the degree of $p$.

Note: that the coefficients come from a field is important. In the ring $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$ the polynomial $x^2-1$ has four roots, since every odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.
It factors as
$$
x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x-7) = (x-3)(x-5).
$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).